# "Archiving" csv into archive folder

Tags: powershell, csv, timestamp, archive

I have a script that runs a sql query and then output the data to

```
C:\audit\results.csv
```

If this was run today, I'd like the file to be saved like the following in addition to the location above.

```
C:\audit\archive\results_20130313_0243.csv
```

In my current script I have the following, however it seems cumbersome and one too many steps.

```
$archiveName = "results $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"
Copy-Item "C:\audit\results.csv" "C:\audit\archive\results.csv"
Rename-item "C:\audit\archive\results.csv" $archiveName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed. Something like this should suffice:

```
cp "C:\audit\results.csv" "C:\audit\archive\results_$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd_HHmm).csv"
```

Comment: well that is certainly far easier! is there a convenient getdate function for the format that I would like? see the middle gray box

Comment: `Get-Date` doesn't have a pre-defined alias, but of course you can define one yourself: `New-Alias gd Get-Date`.

Comment: I think he means the format. Try using `get-date -f yyyyMMdd_hhmm`.

Comment: @Graimer Of course. *\*slaps self\** I believe it should be `HHmm` rather than `hhmm`, though.

Comment: Sure. It depends if he wants 24h or 12h clock, but he didn't specify it. 02 could be either way ^^